# Javascript nesting futile functions

Tags: javascript, class

I have a Notification class that I would like would give this sort of JSON structure:

```
{
   "title":"title1",
   "author":{
      "name":"author1"
   }
}
```

In my constructor I pass the title and author parameters, the only problem is that author is a class of itself. I am wondering if I have to declare an author class in my file (which I would avoid) or if I can nest the author class directly in the notification class. I tried in this manner but it hasn't worked:

```
class Notification {

    constructor(title, author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = class {
            name = author
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `this.author = { name: author }`?

Comment: "*author is a class of itself*" - do you mean that you actually have a `class Author {…}` somewhere else already, or do you just mean that the `author` object in your example structure is nested? The latter doesn't require classes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a class should be done prior to initialising its instances.

In your case (assuming the `author` in the constructor of `Notification` is actually a string, representing its name):

```js
class Author {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Notification {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = new Author(author);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just initialise a specific instance of an object that represents `Author`:

```js
class Notification {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = { name: author };
  }
}
```